# Can a simple analytical expression for the maximum value of $6 \cos \phi - \cos^2 \phi -8 \sin \phi$ be found?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, maxima-minima

I'm trying to solve a math problem and have reduced it to finding the maximum and minimum values of the function specified in the title of this post, and I have no idea how I can derive simple analytical expressions for those values.

It's a homework problem for university students, so the answer and the solution are supposed to be simple.

By introducing $x = \cos \phi$, I can obtain a fourth-order polynomial equation for the positions of the maximum and minimum:
$$
x^4-6x^3+24x^2+6x-9=0.
$$
But I don't see how I can analytically find its roots. I know that each fourth-order polynomial equation can be solved analytically by using some extremely complicated formulas, but students are surely not supposed to bother using them.

Does it look like the lecturer made a typo in the formulation of the problem, or is there a simple solution?

---

P.S. Just in case, here's the original problem:

> Find the maximum and minimum values of  $w(x,y,z) = 6x - x^2 - 8 y + z^3$ under the condition $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$.

I proved and also numerically verified that that those values are reached somewhere at the equator of the sphere, that is, at $z=0$, $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. This is how the problem is reduced to finding the maximum and minimum values of the function specified in the title of this post.

Comment: I think  Lagrange multipliers method may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, the answer to your question is "no":  there *are* exact expressions for the solutions to that trigonometric equation, but they are *not* simple.

For the function $ \ w(x,y,z) \ = \ 6x - x^2 - 8 y + z^3 \ $ over the closed unit ball $ \ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ \leq \ 1 \ \ , \ $ you found that there are no critical points in the interior and that the extrema of the function lie on the "equator" ( $  z \ = \ 0  $ ) of the spherical surface.  Were the function there simply $ \ w'(x \ , \ y \ , \ 0) \ = \ 6x -  8 y  \ \ , \ $ the trigonometric version could be written as
$$ 6·\cos \phi \ - \ 8·\sin \phi \ \ = \ \ 10·\left( \ \frac35·\cos \phi \ - \ \frac45·\sin \phi \ \right) \ \ , \ $$
whereupon, making the assignment $ \ \cos \alpha \ = \ \frac35 \ \ , \ \ \sin \alpha \ = \ \frac45 \ \ , \ $ we can apply the "angle-addition" for cosine to write $ \ w'(\phi \ , \ 0) \ = \ 10·\cos( \  \phi \ + \ \alpha \ )  \ \ , \ $ which has its maximum of $ \ +10 \ $ for $ \ \phi \ = \ 2 \pi - \arctan \frac43 \ \approx \ 5.356 \ $ and its minimum of $ \ -10 \ $ for $ \ \phi \ = \  \pi - \arctan \frac43 \ \approx \ 2.214 \ \   $ [the red dots in the graph below].  However, the additional term in $ \ w(\phi \ , \ 0) \ = \ 10·\cos( \  \phi \ + \ \alpha \ ) \ - \ \cos^2 \phi  \ \ $ has a period of $ \ \pi \ \ ; \ $ it has the effect of lowering the function curve for $ \ w' \ \   $ and shifting asymmetrically the angles at which the extrema occur.  Exact expressions for these angles exist, as shown (for instance) by WolframAlpha, but they involve sums with nested radicals; the same is the case for the quartic polynomial you give.  The numerical approximations are $ \ +9.683 \ $ at $ \ \phi \ \approx \ 5.270 \ $ and $ \ -10.408 \ $ at $ \ \phi \ \approx \ 2.316 \ \  $ [blue dots].  If a simple solution was indeed intended in the given problem, perhaps there is a "typo" in the function equation (or the poser of the problem had not worked out a solution in advance).

[image]

$$ \ \ $$

To follow through on the suggestion of **Sourav Ghosh**, the Lagrange method presents a similar situation.  The equations are
$$ (6 \ - \ 2x) \ - \ \lambda·2x \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ ( \ 1 \ + \ \lambda \ )·2x \ \ = \ \ 6 \ \ , $$
$$ -8 \ - \ \lambda·2y \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \   , \ \ 3z^2 \ - \ \lambda·2z \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ z·( \ 3z \ - \ 2\lambda \ ) \ \ = \ \ 0 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \lambda \ \ = \ \ \frac{3 \ - \ x}{x} \ \ = \ \ -\frac{4}{y} \ \ = \ \ \frac{3·z}{2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ y \ \ = \ \ \frac{4·x}{x \ - \ 3} \ \ \left[ \ \ = \ \ -\frac{8}{3·z} \ \ \right] \ \ . $$

We then consider two cases.  If $ \ z \ \neq \ 0 \ \ , \ $ we apply all three results for the variables in the sphere equation $ \ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ = \ 1 \ \  $ to obtain two non-equatorial extrema

$$ x \ \approx \ -0.3664 \ \ , \ \ y \ \approx \ +0.4354 \ \ , \ \ z \ \approx \ +0.8223 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ w(x \ , \ y \ , \ z) \ \approx \ -5.260 \ \ , $$
$$ x \ \approx \ +0.3961 \ \ , \ \ y \ \approx \ -0.6084 \ \ , \ \ z \ \approx \ -0.6876 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ w(x \ , \ y \ , \ z) \ \approx \ +6.762 \ \ . $$

On the other hand, for $ \ z \ = \ 0 \ , \ \ $ we insert the relation between $ \ y \ $ and $ \ x \ $ into $ \ x^2 + y^2 + 0^2 \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ $ yielding the absolute extrema

$$ x \ \approx \ -0.6767 \ \ , \ \ y \ \approx \ +0.7362 \ \ [ \ \phi \ \approx \ 2.3141 \ ]  \ \ \rightarrow \ \ w(x \ , \ y \ , \ 0) \ \approx \ -10.4077 \ \ , $$
$$ x \ \approx \ +0.5260 \ \ , \ \ y \ \approx \ -0.8504 \ \ [ \ \phi \ \approx \ 5.2663 \ ]  \ \ \rightarrow \ \ w(x \ , \ y \ , \ 0) \ \approx \ +9.6825 \ \ , $$
in agreement with the trigonometric results presented above.

Here again, there are exact "analytical" values to be had, but do we *want* to write them out?